# Report Structure in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a dynamic structure in a data base so that I can configure reports from backend dynamically. Need  your help in designing the backend structure. Here is my idea

Table ReportAccountMap

```
AccountId
ReportId
IsActive
```

One account can map to multiple ReportIds, accountid is unique

Table Report_MetaData

```
StructureId
DataSetName
DataSetSourceId
DataSetSourceServiceAPI
```

Table Report_Structure

```
ReportId
StructureId
```

I am trying to find what constraints to put in the above structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want foreign key constraints between the tables, and a primary key in each table.

Comment: How can  `AccountID`in table `ReportAccountMap` be unique if there can be more than one reports mapped to it ?

Comment: AccountId 1 can map to ReportId 1

Comment: Account 2 can also map to Report 1 since it used the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id into ReportAccountMap and Report_Structure so your primary key there will be one-dimensional.

ReportAccountMap.AccountId needs to be a foreign key to Account(id)

(ReportAccountMap.AccountId, ReportAccountMap.ReportId) needs to be unique

Report_MetaData.StructureId needs to be a foreign key to Report(StructureId)

Report_MetaData(DataSetSourceId) needs to be a foreign key to DataSetSource(Id)

Report_Structure.ReportId needs to be a foreign key to Report(Id)

Report_Structure.StructureId needs to be a foreign key to (Structure.Id)

At least this is how I understood your intention. It would not hurt to add indexes for the n:m tables taking into account the optimal direction.

Also, ReportAccountMap is needed, since it is different from Account logically and it also has an attribute called IsActive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you suggesting creation of new table Report ( Id,StrucutureId) Id maps to ReportAccountMap table. Sorry I am confused now

Comment: @user1143726, no, I was just assuming you have such a rable since you have a ReportId.

Comment: No I dont have such a table. May be makes sense to have such a table which maps to Id of the AccountReport table.

Comment: @user1143726 yes, it makes sense to have such a table from a logical point of view, since Report is logically a separate entity. If my answer solved the problem you faced, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Here is the structure I am thinking of now

Comment: @user1143726 I do not see the structure.

Comment: I was not thinking of adding Structure Id to report table as 1 report can have multiple elements so it could have multiple structureIds. For instance ReportId1 can map to Str1 ,str2 and str3 and report Id 2 can map to str1,str2,str3 and str4

Comment: @user1143726 yes, you are right. Report should contain an Id, a name and possibly some other useful attributes, depending on your task.

Comment: So here is the structure Report(ReportId,Report) ,ReportAccountMap(ReportId,AccountId,Isactive),Report_Meta_data_Structure(ReportId,StrutureId) and ReportMetaData(StructureId,DataResourceId)

Comment: @user1143726 this seems to be a good approach, but don't forget to make (ReportId, StructureId) at the Report_Meta_data_Structure table unique, since we do not want redundancy there.